How to I call/trigger a ribbon control sub from a regular sub?
I have a ribbon that has a button I want to call using a regular sub routine in a macro.
Public Rib As IRibbonUI
Sub RibbonOnLoad(ribbon As IRibbonUI)
    On Error GoTo this
    Set Rib = ribbon
    
    If Application.Version > 12 Then
        Rib.ActivateTab "tabColtar"
    End If
this:
End Sub

this is the button on addin i want to call:
Sub NeedToCallThis(control As IRibbonControl)
   ...
end sub

this is my sub routine i want to call/trigger/run the button from:
Sub CallingAddinButton()
    ...how to call the "NeedToCallThis" ribbon button?
end sub


This question is similar to: Simulate, through a macro, a click on a custom ribbon item. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I don't think it is the same.

If you don't think so, edit your question so it's more clearly its own issue.

It would help to show the code in the NeedToCallThis Sub ... particularly to understand if and how the IRibbonControl object (ie control) is used.

@JohnM it is just regular macro code. My need is to learn how to call that "NeedToCallThis" control from an regular macro.

The answer depends on if / how you are using the IRibbonControl object within NeedToCallThis ... "regular macro code" doesn't help to clarify that

the IRibbonControl loads the addin that has the button "NeedToCallThis" I want to also call it from an macro.

Assuming that you are not referencing the parameter in the Sub (e.g. using a switch statement on control.ID to have the Sub do different things based on which Control on the Ribbon called it), you can just pass it Nothing, like this:
Sub CallingAddinButton()
    NeedToCallThis Nothing
End Sub

(Note: all Properties of IRibbonControl objects are Read Only — so even if you Dim ircTemp AS IRibbonControl to create a new/virtual IRibbonControl, you cannot assign a value to ircTemp.id to pass with NeedToCallThis ircTEMP)
